# How to add a title to a .csv file?

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql

I have some .csv files I'm outputting to email for reporting purposes. I'm happy with that. BUT, I want to make the reports a bit more readable by adding a "Title"

This is just an example of the column structure currently... i'd like to add something before all this that has "Title"

```
create or replace procedure EST_PROC is
file_handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
v_csv_name varchar2(40);
v_link_name varchar2(10);
begin

SELECT tablename into v_csv_name
FROM table_tracker
WHERE
CREATED_AT = (select MAX(CREATED_AT) from table_tracker);

select distinct link_name into v_link_name from link_name;

file_handle := utl_file.fopen('ESTIMATES_CSV',
v_csv_name||'.csv',
'w', 32767);
utl_file.put_line(file_handle, 'TARGET_TABLESPACE,MAX_ALLOC_GB,ALLOC_GB,USED_GB,PERC_USED');
for rws in (select TARGET_TABLESPACE,
MAX_ALLOC_GB,
ALLOC_GB,
USED_GB,
PERC_USED
from ESTIMATE where link = v_link_name)

loop
utl_file.put_line(file_handle,
rws.TARGET_TABLESPACE || ',' ||
rws.MAX_ALLOC_GB || ',' ||
rws.ALLOC_GB || ',' ||
rws.USED_GB || ',' ||
rws.PERC_USED -- your columns here
);
end loop;
utl_file.fclose(file_handle);
end EST_PROC;
```

^ This creates the .csv file in the directory on the server, I just want a heading beforehand.

Comment: Without a sample of the output you want we're just guessing here. Please edit your question and give us an example of what you're looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Most CSV parsers expect the first line to have the column headings, seems a little strange to add a "title". But to each his own :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO your first approach (writing the title using UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE before outputting the .csv data) seems reasonable.

However...if you're not happy with that you might trying changing your cursor to return the title before the data by UNION'ing it in:

```
SELECT 'Y' AS IS_TITLE,
       'TGTBSP,MAX GB,ALLOC GB,USED GB,PERC DB,PERC USED' AS TARGET_TABLESPACE,
       NULL AS MAX_ALLOC_GB,
       NULL AS ALLOC_GB
       NULL AS USED_GB,
       NULL AS PERC_GB,
       NULL AS PERC_USED
  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
select 'N' AS IS_TITLE,
       TARGET_TABLESPACE,
       MAX_ALLOC_GB,
       ALLOC_GB,
       USED_GB,
       PERC_USED
  from ESTIMATE
  where link = v_link_name
```

Now, when you get a row with `IS_TITLE = 'Y'` you only output the `TARGET_TABLESPACE` column, which contains your titles. If `IS_TITLE = 'N'` you output all your data fields with appropriate formatting, commas, etc.

Best of luck.

### EDIT

Based on the comment below, add the following immediately after the `UTL_FILE.FOPEN` call:

```
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, 'G''day. This output shows blah blah blah...');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, ' ');
```

Give that a shot.

All the best.

Comment: That's good to know, but what are you looking for in the output that you're not getting now? Just saying "I want a heading" doesn't make sense to me, as you're already writing out a heading line. Couldn't you just add another PUT_LINE? ???

Comment: Well, the .csv file comes through with all its columns having headers. I just want a title for it at the top. So you open it and it says "G'day. This output shows blah blah blah..." and then two lines later, the rest of it is shown. And I don't know how to do that...

Comment: Thanks Bob, I tried adding in the extra lines but there's a compilation error: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'

Comment: Ah no - it works if you add the file handler first - sorted!! Thanks Bob :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking?

```
select 'Title' as Col1, TARGET_TABLESPACE,
MAX_ALLOC_GB,
ALLOC_GB,
USED_GB,
PERC_USED
from ESTIMATE where link = v_link_name
```

Comment: No - thanks... this is just for SQLPLUS Reporting. My current code generates a .csv which opens just like a spreadsheet, with columns in the .csv showing the SQL output. I am trying to add a Title to the .csv file and maintain the column formatting in the rest of the file.